# basic planet wars ai issues

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I am programming a very basic bot for planet wars in java and I cant seem to find the errors in my code. I am receiving a few different error messages but the main issue for me is the error: class, interface, or enum expected. Ive checked my brackets about a thousand times. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my bot code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import shared.Planet;
import shared.PlanetWars;

public class MyNewBot {

public static void doTurn(PlanetWars pw) {
    // (1) If we currently have a fleet in flight, then do nothing until
    // it arrives.
    if (pw.myFleets().size() >= 10) {
        return;
    }

    // (2) Pick one of my planets based on the number of ships 

    Planet source = null;
    int largestForce = 0;
    for (Planet p : pw.myPlanets()){
        int force = pw.numShips();
        if( force > largestForce){
            largestForce = force;
            source = p;
        }
    }

    // (3) Pick a target planet at random.
    Planet dest = null;
    int highestGrowthRate = 0;
    int shortestDistance = 9999;
    for (Planet p = pw.notMyPlanets()){
        int growthRate = pw.growthRate();
        if( growthRate > highestGrowthRate){
            highestGrowthRate = growthRate;
            dest = p;
        }else if (growthRate == highestGrowthRate){
            int distance = pw.distance(source,p);
            if (distance < shortestDistance){
                shortestDistance = distance;
                dest = p;
            }
        }
    }


    // (4) Send half the ships from source to destination.
    if (source != null && dest != null) {
        int numShips = source.numShips() / 2;
        pw.issueOrder(source, dest, numShips);
    }
}

// Ignore the main method unless you know what you're doing.
// Refer to the doTurn function to code your bot.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "";
    String message = "";
    int c;
    try {
        while ((c = System.in.read()) >= 0) {
            switch (c) {
            case '\n':
                if (line.equals("go")) {
                    PlanetWars pw = new PlanetWars(message);
                    doTurn(pw);
                    pw.finishTurn();
                    message = "";
                } else {
                    message += line + "\n";
                }
                line = "";
                break;
            default:
                line += (char) c;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Owned.
    }
}

}
```

and the supporting class files:

```
package shared;
public class Planet implements Cloneable {

private int planetID;
private int owner;
private int numShips;
private int growthRate;
private double x, y;

public Planet(int planetID, int owner, int numShips, int growthRate,
        double x, double y) {
    this.planetID = planetID;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.numShips = numShips;
    this.growthRate = growthRate;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int planetID() {
    return planetID;
}

public int owner() {
    return owner;
}

public int numShips() {
    return numShips;
}

public int growthRate() {
    return growthRate;
}

public double x() {
    return x;
}

public double y() {
    return y;
}

public void owner(int newOwner) {
    this.owner = newOwner;
}

public void numShips(int newNumShips) {
    this.numShips = newNumShips;
}

public void addShips(int amount) {
    numShips += amount;
}

public void removeShips(int amount) {
    numShips -= amount;
}

private Planet(Planet _p) {
    planetID = _p.planetID;
    owner = _p.owner;
    numShips = _p.numShips;
    growthRate = _p.growthRate;
    x = _p.x;
    y = _p.y;
}

public Object clone() {
    return new Planet(this);
}
}

package shared;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class PlanetWars {
// Constructs a PlanetWars object instance, given a string containing a
// description of a game state.
public PlanetWars(String gameStateString) {
    planets = new ArrayList<Planet>();
    fleets = new ArrayList<Fleet>();
    parseGameState(gameStateString);
}

// Returns the number of planets. Planets are numbered starting with 0.
public int numPlanets() {
    return planets.size();
}

// Returns the planet with the given planet_id. There are NumPlanets()
// planets. They are numbered starting at 0.
public Planet getPlanet(int planetID) {
    return planets.get(planetID);
}

// Returns the number of fleets.
public int numFleets() {
    return fleets.size();
}

// Returns the fleet with the given fleet_id. Fleets are numbered starting
// with 0. There are NumFleets() fleets. fleet_id's are not consistent from
// one turn to the next.
public Fleet getFleet(int fleetID) {
    return fleets.get(fleetID);
}

// Returns a list of all the planets.
public List<Planet> planets() {
    return planets;
}

// Return a list of all the planets owned by the current player. By
// convention, the current player is always player number 1.
public List<Planet> myPlanets() {
    List<Planet> r = new ArrayList<Planet>();
    for (Planet p : planets) {
        if (p.owner() == 1) {
            r.add(p);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// Return a list of all neutral planets.
public List<Planet> neutralPlanets() {
    List<Planet> r = new ArrayList<Planet>();
    for (Planet p : planets) {
        if (p.owner() == 0) {
            r.add(p);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// Return a list of all the planets owned by rival players. This excludes
// planets owned by the current player, as well as neutral planets.
public List<Planet> enemyPlanets() {
    List<Planet> r = new ArrayList<Planet>();
    for (Planet p : planets) {
        if (p.owner() >= 2) {
            r.add(p);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// Return a list of all the planets that are not owned by the current
// player. This includes all enemy planets and neutral planets.
public List<Planet> notMyPlanets() {
    List<Planet> r = new ArrayList<Planet>();
    for (Planet p : planets) {
        if (p.owner() != 1) {
            r.add(p);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// Return a list of all the fleets.
public List<Fleet> fleets() {
    List<Fleet> r = new ArrayList<Fleet>();
    for (Fleet f : fleets) {
        r.add(f);
    }
    return r;
}

// Return a list of all the fleets owned by the current player.
public List<Fleet> myFleets() {
    List<Fleet> r = new ArrayList<Fleet>();
    for (Fleet f : fleets) {
        if (f.owner() == 1) {
            r.add(f);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// Return a list of all the fleets owned by enemy players.
public List<Fleet> enemyFleets() {
    List<Fleet> r = new ArrayList<Fleet>();
    for (Fleet f : fleets) {
        if (f.owner() != 1) {
            r.add(f);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// Returns the distance between two planets, rounded up to the next highest
// integer. This is the number of discrete time steps it takes to get
// between the two planets.
public int distance(int sourcePlanet, int destinationPlanet) {
    Planet source = planets.get(sourcePlanet);
    Planet destination = planets.get(destinationPlanet);
    double dx = source.x() - destination.x();
    double dy = source.y() - destination.y();
    return (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
}

// Returns the distance between two planets, rounded up to the next highest
// integer. This is the number of discrete time steps it takes to get
// between the two planets.
public int distance(Planet source, Planet destination) {
    double dx = source.x() - destination.x();
    double dy = source.y() - destination.y();
    return (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
}

// Sends an order to the game engine. An order is composed of a source
// planet number, a destination planet number, and a number of ships. A
// few things to keep in mind:
// * you can issue many orders per turn if you like.
// * the planets are numbered starting at zero, not one.
// * you must own the source planet. If you break this rule, the game
// engine kicks your bot out of the game instantly.
// * you can't move more ships than are currently on the source planet.
// * the ships will take a few turns to reach their destination. Travel
// is not instant. See the Distance() function for more info.
public void issueOrder(int sourcePlanet, int destinationPlanet, int 
numShips) {
    System.out.println("" + sourcePlanet + " " + destinationPlanet + " "
            + numShips);
    System.out.flush();
}

// Sends an order to the game engine. An order is composed of a source
// planet number, a destination planet number, and a number of ships. A
// few things to keep in mind:
// * you can issue many orders per turn if you like.
// * the planets are numbered starting at zero, not one.
// * you must own the source planet. If you break this rule, the game
// engine kicks your bot out of the game instantly.
// * you can't move more ships than are currently on the source planet.
// * the ships will take a few turns to reach their destination. Travel
// is not instant. See the Distance() function for more info.
public void issueOrder(Planet source, Planet dest, int numShips) {
    System.out.println("" + source.planetID() + " " + dest.planetID() + " "
            + numShips);
    System.out.flush();
}

// Sends the game engine a message to let it know that we're done sending
// orders. This signifies the end of our turn.
public void finishTurn() {
    System.out.println("go");
    System.out.flush();
}

// Returns true if the named player owns at least one planet or fleet.
// Otherwise, the player is deemed to be dead and false is returned.
public boolean isAlive(int playerID) {
    for (Planet p : planets) {
        if (p.owner() == playerID) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    for (Fleet f : fleets) {
        if (f.owner() == playerID) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// If the game is not yet over (ie: at least two players have planets or
// fleets remaining), returns -1. If the game is over (ie: only one player
// is left) then that player's number is returned. If there are no
// remaining players, then the game is a draw and 0 is returned.
public int winner() {
    Set<Integer> remainingPlayers = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (Planet p : planets) {
        remainingPlayers.add(p.owner());
    }
    for (Fleet f : fleets) {
        remainingPlayers.add(f.owner());
    }
    switch (remainingPlayers.size()) {
    case 0:
        return 0;
    case 1:
        return ((Integer) remainingPlayers.toArray()[0]).intValue();
    default:
        return -1;
    }
}

// Returns the number of ships that the current player has, either located
// on planets or in flight.
public int numShips(int playerID) {
    int numShips = 0;
    for (Planet p : planets) {
        if (p.owner() == playerID) {
            numShips += p.numShips();
        }
    }
    for (Fleet f : fleets) {
        if (f.owner() == playerID) {
            numShips += f.numShips();
        }
    }
    return numShips;
}

// Returns the production of the given player.
public int production(int playerID) {
    int prod = 0;
    for (Planet p : planets) {
        if (p.owner() == playerID) {
            prod += p.growthRate();
        }
    }
    return prod;
}

// Parses a game state from a string. On success, returns 1. On failure,
// returns 0.
private int parseGameState(String s) {
    planets.clear();
    fleets.clear();
    int planetID = 0;
    String[] lines = s.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
        String line = lines[i];
        int commentBegin = line.indexOf('#');
        if (commentBegin >= 0) {
            line = line.substring(0, commentBegin);
        }
        if (line.trim().length() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        if (tokens.length == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (tokens[0].equals("P")) {
            if (tokens.length != 6) {
                return 0;
            }
            double x = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
            double y = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
            int owner = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
            int numShips = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
            int growthRate = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);
            Planet p = new Planet(planetID++, owner, numShips, growthRate,
                    x, y);
            planets.add(p);
        } else if (tokens[0].equals("F")) {
            if (tokens.length != 7) {
                return 0;
            }
            int owner = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            int numShips = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            int source = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
            int destination = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
            int totalTripLength = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);
            int turnsRemaining = Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]);
            Fleet f = new Fleet(owner, numShips, source, destination,
                    totalTripLength, turnsRemaining);
            fleets.add(f);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// Store all the planets and fleets. OMG we wouldn't wanna lose all the
// planets and fleets, would we!?
private ArrayList<Planet> planets;
private ArrayList<Fleet> fleets;
}

package shared;
public class Fleet implements Comparable<Fleet>, Cloneable {

private int owner;
private int numShips;
private int sourcePlanet;
private int destinationPlanet;
private int totalTripLength;
private int turnsRemaining;

public Fleet(int owner, int numShips, int sourcePlanet,
        int destinationPlanet, int totalTripLength, int turnsRemaining) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.numShips = numShips;
    this.sourcePlanet = sourcePlanet;
    this.destinationPlanet = destinationPlanet;
    this.totalTripLength = totalTripLength;
    this.turnsRemaining = turnsRemaining;
}

public Fleet(int owner, int numShips) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.numShips = numShips;
    this.sourcePlanet = -1;
    this.destinationPlanet = -1;
    this.totalTripLength = -1;
    this.turnsRemaining = -1;
}

public int owner() {
    return owner;
}

public int numShips() {
    return numShips;
}

public int sourcePlanet() {
    return sourcePlanet;
}

public int destinationPlanet() {
    return destinationPlanet;
}

public int totalTripLength() {
    return totalTripLength;
}

public int turnsRemaining() {
    return turnsRemaining;
}

public void removeShips(int amount) {
    numShips -= amount;
}

// Subtracts one turn remaining. Call this function to make the fleet get
// one turn closer to its destination.
public void TimeStep() {
    if (turnsRemaining > 0) {
        --turnsRemaining;
    } else {
        turnsRemaining = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Fleet f) {
    return this.numShips - f.numShips;
}

private Fleet(Fleet _f) {
    owner = _f.owner;
    numShips = _f.numShips;
    sourcePlanet = _f.sourcePlanet;
    destinationPlanet = _f.destinationPlanet;
    totalTripLength = _f.totalTripLength;
    turnsRemaining = _f.turnsRemaining;
}

public Object clone() {
    return new Fleet(this);
}
}
```

Comment: On which line do you receive such error?

Answer (score 0):

`for (Planet p = pw.notMyPlanets()){` should be `for (Planet p : pw.notMyPlanets()){`.

You've not posted the `Fleet` class, so as it is the code won't compile for me.  However, the above is the only other error I could see.